# Cycling Through Section tags: Stops After 2nd Section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of section tags which I am trying to cycle through using jQuery:

```
<ul id="office-nav">
<li class="prev"><a href="">Previous</a></li>
<li>Next Location</li>
<li class="next"><a href="">Next</a></li>
</ul>

<article id="offices">

<section class="office1">
<h3>Office 1</h3>
</section><!--end office1-->

<section class="office2">
<h3>Office 2</h3>
</section><!--end office2-->

<section class="office3">
<h3>Office 3</h3>
</section><!--end office3-->

</article><!--end offices-->
```

The CSS:

```
#offices section{display:none;width:300px;height:300px;}
#offices section.office1{display:block;background-color:red;}
#offices section.office2{background-color:yellow;}
#offices section.office3{background-color:orange;}
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
var visibleBox = $('#offices section:visible');
var nextToShow = $(visibleBox).next('section:hidden');

$("#office-nav li.next a").click(function(event) {
    visibleBox.hide();
    if (nextToShow.length > 0) {
        nextToShow.show();
    } else {
        $('#offices section:hidden:first').show();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This cycles up to `.office2` for me, but nothing past that. Also, how would I rewrite a reverse function to cycle backwards?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pwb6D/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only getting the visible `section` element on load, you need to update the `visibleBox` and `nextToShow` variables within the `click` event handler.

Put:

```
var visibleBox = $('#offices section:visible');
var nextToShow = $(visibleBox).next('section:hidden');
```

inside the `click` event handler so it will be updated each time the user clicks the `next`/`prev` buttons:

```
$("#office-nav li.next a").click(function(event) {
    var visibleBox = $('#offices section:visible');
    var nextToShow = $(visibleBox).next('section:hidden');
    visibleBox.hide();
    if (nextToShow.length > 0) {
        nextToShow.show();
    } else {
        $('#offices section:hidden:first').show();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pwb6D/4/

**UPDATE**

You can optimize your code a bit by caching all the `section` tags and using a counting variable to keep track of the current state:

```
//cache all the sections, how many sections there are, and set the current section to the first (zero based index)
var $all_sections = $('#offices').children('section'),
    curr_section  = 0,
    section_count = $all_sections.length;

//bind click event handler to "next" button
$("#office-nav li.next a").click(function(event) {

    //hide the section that was showing
    $all_sections.eq(curr_section).hide();

    //increment the curr_section variable
    curr_section++;

    //check to make sure there is still another hidden section to show, if not reset the curr_section variable to zero
    if (curr_section >= section_count) {
        curr_section = 0;
    }

    //show the next section
    $all_sections.eq(curr_section).show();

    //prevent the default click behavior of the "next" link
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pwb6D/5/

**UPDATE**

You can use this same code with a few tweaks to create the functionality for your "prev" link:

```
$("#office-nav .prev a").click(function(event) {
    $all_sections.eq(curr_section).hide();

    //increment down instead of up
    curr_section--;

    //check if the new curr_section value is less than zero (instead of larger than the number of sections)
    if (curr_section < 0) {

        //reset curr_section variable to the last section
        curr_section = (section_count - 1);
    }
    $all_sections.eq(curr_section).show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do the exact same thing but in reverse for `#office-nav li.prev a`?

Comment: @Yahreen You sure can, you just bind the same `click` event handler to the "prev" link and change a couple lines of code to do the opposite (increment down instead of up, etc). Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pwb6D/6/

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. This works great. One final question: Is it possible to find the id of the current `section` tag and add it as a hash to the address bar when either `#office-nav .prev a` or `#office-nav .next a` is clicked?

Comment: @Yahreen Just change `$all_sections.eq(curr_section).show();` to `location.hash = $all_sections.eq(curr_section).show().attr('id');`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pwb6D/7/

Comment: I like it. Was thinking about this on the car ride home. This is probably the best way. I didn't like that my solution relied on so many selector lookups.

Comment: How could I go about doing this `location.hash = $all_sections.eq(curr_section).show().attr('id');` but for your first example?

Comment: Change `nextToShow.show();` to `location.hash = nextToShow.show().attr('id');` and `$('#offices section:hidden:first').show();` to `location.hash = $('#offices section:hidden:first').show().attr('id');`. The basic idea is to get the ID of the element that will be shown and make the `location.hash` element equal to it. Since you can chain function calls in jQuery that's what I am doing, chaining the calls and ending with `.attr('id')` to have the ID saved to the `location.hash` property.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the first visible section in `visibleBox`. This will not get replaced with the newly visible section. Check the below code to fix this.

```
var Boxes = $('#offices');

$("#office-nav li.next a").click(function(event) {

    var visibleBox = Boxes.find('section:visible'), // Find the visible section in article.
        nextToShow = visibleBox.next(); // Get the next section to visible

    visibleBox.hide();
    if (nextToShow.length > 0) {
        nextToShow.show();
    } else {
        $('#offices section:hidden:first').show();
    }

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easier structure to use than your current one and doesn't rely on globals.

http://jsfiddle.net/CQGRL/1

```
$('.office:first').addClass('active'); //show first office

$(".next a").click(function(event) {
    //abort if this is the end of the list
    if ($('.active').is('.office:last')) { return false; }
    //find next office in list and make it active. then remove active class from current
    $('.active').next('.office').addClass('active').end().removeClass('active');
    return false;
});

$(".prev a").click(function(event) {
    //abort if this is the end of the list
    if ($('.active').is('.office:first')) { return false; }
    //find previous office in list and make it active. then remove active class from current    
    $('.active').prev('.office').addClass('active').end().removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This looks pretty good but it doesn't wrap around to the beginning when you go through all of the `section` elements.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover boundary cases

Comment: @Jasper - woops, didn't see that. I have to catch the train now, but my updated answer kind of shows how this could be done. You can check for boundary and then will have to special case wraparound there.